# Parallel RC circuit differential equation for a mechanical engineer

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, transfer-function

For a mechanical engineering course in controls, I was asked to

> Write the differential equation, state equation, and transfer function for this circuit

That's the full text of the problem, and the schematic below is the extent of the other information given)

[image: Circuit diagram]

I assume \$y\$ is the intended output of the system, but beyond that I'm at a loss as to how to go about this (and of course we've done no example problems with circuits [or, indeed, any example problems at all, really]). I tried playing around with Kirchhoff's laws, which I think works out as follows:

\$\ V1 = V_{R_1} + V_{R_2} + y = V_{R_1} + V_{C_1} \$

\$\ i_{R_1} = i_1 + i_2\$

\$\ V_{R_1}/R_1 = Cdv/dt + i_2 \$ (but I can't figure out how to find i2)

I'm a mechanical engineer and have next to no grasp of circuit theory. I think I can deal with the state equation and transfer function half of the problem, but to get there I need to figure out how to get the differential equation. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Homework with no attempt to solve it is off-topic -- please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted so far so that it will be on-topic.

Comment: My bad, I've never posted here before and didn't check the rules carefully enough. I've added what little I was able to figure out, but even after quite a bit of online reading I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: Hint: your states are the capacitor voltages (because \$v_c = \frac{1}{C} \int i_c dt\$).  So at any instant in time, the currents \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$ are determined by the input voltage and the capacitor voltages.  Does that lead you to a system of equations that you can solve?

Comment: Some of your equations are erroneous.  You write \$i_{R_1} = i_1 + i_2\$.  This should be \$i_{R_1} = i_1\$, since loop current \$i_2\$ does not flow in the left-hand loop.  You also write \$\frac{V_{R_1}}{R_1}= C \frac{dv}{dt} + i_2\$.  This should be \$i_{C_1} = C \frac{dv_{C_1}}{dt}\$ with current \$i_{C_1} = i_1 - i_2\$.

The general idea is to use the two current loops to create two simultaneous equations in two unknowns, \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$, then solve the two equations for those unknowns.  Once that is done, you can readily find all other quantities of interest.

Answer (score 0):

First steps may be:

$$i_1=\frac{V_1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\int (i_1 -i_2)\:dt$$
$$i_2=\frac{1}{R_2C_1}\int i_1\:dt-\frac{C_1 +C_2}{R_2C_1C_2}\int i_2\:dt$$

Then differentiate through.